# Sitecore analytics on local dev machine not capturing data

Tags: xconnect, experience-analytics

I've been working through setting up XConnect on a local machine.

Over a few days I've dug through the logs and fixed configuration issues (broken connections strings copied from another environment and certificate errors). I've eliminated all the red error messages at the top of my reports, but XDB is not capturing any data.

I've tried Sitecore's suggestion to redeploy the marketing definitions, but that list is still empty. I'm not sure why they won't populate since no errors are showing up in any log files.

I'm open to any suggestions where to look at this point.

**Update**

I can't expand the Workflow tab on the Marketing Goals content - this is probably what's causing the problem since I can't change the workflow state.

Comment: Do you see issue with collecting data? as you don't see data in interactions table in Shards databases? or you have data in shards but not data in reporting database?. did you check out this link:
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0977445

Comment: I have and I've followed the steps, but my local doesn't have the config file mentioned in the article. I can't find it in the sample configs Sitecore creates either. Is this even supported on XP0?

Comment: Once all the connection string troubles is out of the way, my absolute prime candidate is this. `Ensure that all the layout pages contain the <sc:VisitorIdentification runat="server" /> tag (@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification() helper for MVC websites) in the <head> section.`. Are you sure and double sure you've checked this? The layout you are using DOES include the above, 100%?

Comment: Can you verify that the following services are running:
- Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer
- Sitecore Processign Engine
- Sitecore Marketing Automation Engine

Comment: @jitendra actually I think you may be onto something - I can't expand the Workflow section of my goals! This has to be the problem.

Comment: could you please install sitecore log analyzer and check exactly what errors you have. As this tool will show you distinct error log for xDB and other issues with your instance. You might can update the error log to provide the correct solution. to generate the log you first need to clear all the logs and then reproduce the issues and then check logs

Answer (score 1):

After fixing the configuration issues, you have to rebuild the xDB index to populate the data in your analytics dashboard.

Follow these,

1. Deploy Marketing Definition
2. Rebuild link databases
3. Rebuild xDB index - Open the Command line as administrator and go to the location where the xConnect Search Indexer is running and go to the IndexWorker folder. Run the command `XConnectSearchIndexer -rr`

You can find more details [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/rebuild-the-xdb-index-in-solr.html)

Comment: Nothing gets deployed with the marketing definitions; they're empty. They're always empty and nothing gets deployed when I try to run that task.

Comment: Make sure your marketing items like goals etc are in deployed state before deploying, then rebuild dev indexes. If you still don’t see any data, rebuild reporting db